# Android Studio Espresso Test Recorder Slow

Tags: android, android-studio, user-interface, testing, android-espresso

I am trying to create some Espresso UI tests using Android Studio's inbuilt Espresso Test Recorder. The issue is: when I type it is very slow to appear on the screen.

Anything text entry/keyboard-based takes a while for a single letter to appear. I have tested this on a super simple one view app vs a larger app, with the larger app having an increased delay. I have also tested it on Genymotion vs Android Studio emulators, with the same delay.

Here is a gif of the delay on the single-page app:

[image]

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: I've just started using Espresso and am having the exact same problem. The recorder is basically unusable. Did you ever make any progress on this?

Comment: Sadly I did not, I gave up on using the recorder completely.

Comment: It is probably also one of those tools that only work for Google I/O demo one button apps. ;)

Comment: Still no news about this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Switching to a lower API might help since it worked for me, and it improved the speed performance of the Espresso test recording.

Comment: downgraded from 29 to 28...typing is still slow...but Assertions mouse-over is a lot faster...what api version do you use? @Inventrohyder